# Calling Window Service Method Inside ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I created a small windows service inside my asp.net application. How can I constantly run the window service from my asp.net application?

**Sample Code**

```
public class EmailSender : ServiceBase
{
    public int AdminId = 0;
    public EmailSender(int Id)
    {
        AdminId = Id;
        this.ServiceName = "Email Service";
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.AutoLog = true;            
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");
        this.SendEmail();
    }

    public void SendEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            Admin admin = Admin.GetInstance;
            var response = admin.GetAdminById(AdminId);
            IEnumerable<Employee> SuspendedEmployee = Employee.GetSuspendedEmployee(AdminId);
            foreach (var item in SuspendedEmployee)
            {
                if (DateTime.Today == item.ArchieveDateTo.AddDays(-1))
                {
                    string Message = "Hello " + response.FullName + " Your Employee " + item.FullName + " who was suspended from " + item.ArchieveDateFrom + " to " + item.ArchieveDateTo + " will be expiring tomorrow<br />. Please go to your dashboard to unarchieve the employee";
                    EmailWithAttachment.SendMail(item.Email, Message, "Suspension Reminder");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.WriteErrorLog(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I actually intended to create a separate windows service,but I ended up creating it within the same project. How can I make it to constantly run and send emails?

Comment: Why not move it into a separate project? By the way, writing services by inheriting from `ServiceBase` is very painful. If you're going to create a .NET Windows Service, then I highly recommend [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).

Comment: @mason I actually intend to to it that way but I can't find the window service template when trying to create windows service project

Comment: You don't need a special template. Just write a console application. And read the TopShelf documentation.